# gnome inspect, get gtk widget under cursor

Tags: gtk, gnome, inspect

I am developing an application that can inspect the GUI of gnome application (inspect any application widget like windows accessibilityinsights not only one app).

I want to know in gtk, is there any way to get the widget under the cursor?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to take a look at the GTK inspector utility available for GTK3 and GTK4.  It's a debugger tool on Linux.  Not sure if it is available on Windows or Mac.

Comment: I've looked at the GTK inspector and it looks like  can only inspect one application at a time, I was hoping to find a global inspector throw the total system.

Comment: Okay.  That was the only thing that came to mind.